# How to determine if a circle is inside a circle using Paper.js?

Tags: javascript, geometry, paperjs

How can one determine if a circle is inside another circle? I thought I had it figured out using *isInside* method.

Note: This code will run on http://sketch.paperjs.org

### Expect Circle2 to be inside Circle1

```
var circle1 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 100);
var circle2 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 50);

circle1.strokeWidth = 2;
circle1.strokeColor = "black";
circle1.fillColor = "blue";
circle2.strokeWidth = 2;
circle2.strokeColor = "black";
circle2.fillColor = "green";

console.log(circle1.isInside(circle2));
console.log(circle2.isInside(circle1));
```

### Outputs:

> false false

Answer (score 2):

To know if `circle_small` with radius `Rs` is enterely inside `circle_big` with radius `Rb` just check that the distance between their centers (Cb, Cs) is *less than* `Rb-Rs`.

If you allow both circles "touch" in one point then the condition is *less or equal* to `Rb-Rs`.

General case:

```
var discen = Math.sqrt( (Cb_x - Cs_x)*(Cb_x - Cs_x) + (Cb_y - Cs_y)*(Cb_y - Cs_y) );
var radiff = Rb - Rs;
if (discen < radiff)
    //circle_small fully inside circle_big, no touching point
else if ( Math.abs(discen-radiff) < 0.0001 ) //better that discen==radiff
    //circle_small fully inside circle_big, one tangent common (touching point)
else if (discen < Rb+Rs)
    //Both circles intersect, partially one inside the other
else if ( Math.abs(discen-Rb-Rs) < 0.0001 )
    //Circles are exterior, but they contact at one point (they're tangent to each other)
else
    //Not intersecting circles
```

**Note:**

About the "*better than a==b*" thing, it's for the case where `a` or `b` are not integers. For floats some digits likely get lost: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comparing `a-b`, in absolute value, with some small thereshold make the comparison valid.

Comment: can you explain why < is better than ==.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [isInside](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#isinside-rect) requires a rectangle object to be passed in as a parameter, not a path.

### Working Code

```
var circle1 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 100);
var circle2 = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 50);

circle1.strokeWidth = 2;
circle1.strokeColor = "black";
circle1.fillColor = "blue";
circle2.strokeWidth = 2;
circle2.strokeColor = "black";
circle2.fillColor = "green";

console.log(circle1.isInside(circle2.bounds));
console.log(circle2.isInside(circle1.bounds));
```

### Outputs:

> false true